# Better way to Write this Classic ASP Code

Tags: unmanaged

This code works but when adding 1000 characters into it,  the web page breaks and does not updated the record in SQL.

```
Set objRecordset3 = cn3.Execute("INSERT INTO MainDB SET Biography = '" & session("Biography") & "' WHERE ID = '" & session("ID") & "'")
```

Can anyone offer me a better way to write an UPDATE that will update at least 3,000 characters instead of 200 which this one can do?

Greatly appreciate your input.

Running Classic ASP on Windows 2008 sp2 and SQL 2005.

Comment: Maybe the column Biography in the database is limited to only 200 characters? Then you just have to change the definition of the column in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your input NineBerry ...  The column in the database is set at 6000 with datatype as VarChar.   Should I change the DataType to something better and if so what?